# Comparing a dictionary of values to a list of values

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to compare a list of pixel R/G/B values that I'm obtaining from an image, to predefined dictionary of RGB values. My question is, what would be the most pythonic (and easiest) way to compare each RGB pixel value taken from an image to a predefined dictionary value.

**Updated:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Image

img = Image.open("/home/user/Pictures/pic.jpg")
pix = img.load()

    width, height = img.size #Image size

    pixels = list(img.getdata())

       #used for testing 

picture_colours = {
        (1, 1, 1): 'known1',
        (4, 4, 4): 'known2',
        (7, 3, 0): 'known3',
        (8, 3, 0): 'known4',
        (9, 4, 0): 'known5',
        (10, 5, 1): 'known6',
        (11, 6, 2): 'known7',
        (12, 7, 3): 'known8',
        (13, 8, 4): 'known9',
        (12, 7, 3): 'known10'

}
colour_type = picture_colours.get(pixels, 'no match')
match = 0 #default value

for pixel in pixels:
        print pixel #used to ensure pixels are in the (x, x ,x) format
        colour_type = picture_colours.get(pixel, 'no match')
        print colour_type #printing either 'no match' or one of the dictionary names(w1,c,asian)
        if(colour_type != 'no match'):
                match = match + 1 #For every matched pixel, + 1

        if(match >= 30):
                print "\n\n\n\n The image matches the data in the corpus"
                break
```

Comment: Why dictionaries? Why not just set the tones to be tuples with (r,g,b) as numbers. This is safer due to the immutability of tuples and is as fast, just replacing key lookup with index lookup. Not only that, but iterating over a dictionary returns keys, where as iterating through a tuple returns values.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was working on a colleagues old code and it didn't cross my mind to change the tones to tuples. Another question for you, could I have used lists as well?

Comment: Absolutely. In Python all basic containers (lists, tuples) work very similarly, with their primary difference being mutability. In this case, it seems like you want colors tied to specific rgb values, so an immutable data type is the safer way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've got this slightly the wrong way around. Try using a tuple of RGB values as the key to your dictionary, and the "name" of it as the result, then look up the pixel:

```
colours = {
    (247, 217, 214): 'lc',
    (240, 186, 173): 'c'
}

colour_type = colours.get(pixel, 'no match')
```

Just make sure `pixel` is a 3-item tuple of the RGB values, and the above should just work.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two dict values with `==`, and it will do exactly what you'd hoped:

```
>>> {'r': 2, 'g': 3, 'b': 4} == {'g': 3, 'b': 4, 'r': 2}
True
```

So, if `pixels` is a list of lists of dicts, just do:

```
pixels[y][x] == lc
```

If it's not, just write a function that converts one format to the other:

```
def rgbify(rgbtuple):
    return {'r': rgbtuple[0], 'g': rgbtuple[1], 'b': rgbtuple[2]}
rgbify(pixels[y][x]) == lc
```

… or:

```
def rgbify(rgbdict):
    return (rgbdict['r'], rgbdict['g'], rgbdict['b'])
pixels[y][x] == rgbify(lc)
```

But that raises the question of why you want to use a different format in the first place. You're designing at least one of these two things; why design two incompatible formats?

If you're just looking for a way to make things more explicit than just a tuple of three numbers, you might want to consider this:

```
>>> Color = collections.namedtuple('Color' list('rgb'))
>>> lc = Color(r=247, g=217, b=214)
Color(r=247, g=217, b=214)
>>> lc = Color(247, 217, 214)
>>> lc
Color(r=247, g=217, b=214)
>>> lc.r
247
>>> lc == (247, 217, 214)
True
```